# Decomposition of forms on manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, smooth-manifolds, lorentzian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a globally-hyperbolic Lorentzian manifold, i.e. $M=I\times\Sigma$ with $I\subset\mathbb{R}$ being an open interval and $\Sigma$ a spacelike smooth Cauchy hypersurface. The metric is of the form $g=-N^2 \, d t^2+h_t$ with $N$ being a positive function, $h_t$ a time-dependent Riemannian metric on $\Sigma$ and $t:M\to\mathbb{R}$ is a suitable time-function.

Now, any differential form $\omega\in\Omega^k(M)$ can be written in the form
$$\omega=\omega_0\wedge dt+\omega_1$$
where $\omega_{0}$ can be identified with a time-dependent $(k-1)$-form on $\Sigma$ and $\omega_{1}$ with a time-dependent $k$-form on $\Sigma$. (This decomposition is basically obtained by setting $\omega_0:=i_{\partial_t}\omega$). Now, heuristically, this yields a decomposition

$$\Omega^k(M)\cong C^\infty(\mathbb{R},\Omega^{k-1}(\Sigma))\oplus C^\infty(\mathbb{R},\Omega^k(\Sigma)).$$

where the notation $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},\Omega^{\bullet}(\Sigma))$ here might be a bit sloppy$^{1}$, but I think it is clear what I mean. Now, what confuses me is the following:

> If I take $(\omega_0,\omega_1)\in
>  C^\infty(\mathbb{R},\Omega^{k-1}(\Sigma))\oplus
>  C^\infty(\mathbb{R},\Omega^k(\Sigma))$ then also
> $(\partial_t\omega_0,\partial_t\omega_1)\in
>  C^\infty(\mathbb{R},\Omega^{k-1}(\Sigma))\oplus
>  C^\infty(\mathbb{R},\Omega^k(\Sigma))$, more or less by
> definition. So, by the isomorphism above, I would be tempted to say
> that $\omega:=(\partial_t\omega_0)\wedge
>  dt+\partial_t\omega_1\in\Omega^k(M)$.

However, this can clearly not be true, since the partial derivative of a tensor is in general not a tensor (at least when $N\neq 1$, otherwise $\partial_t=\nabla_{\partial_t}$ since the relevant Christoffel symbols vanish in this special case). Where is the error in my arguments?

---

$^1$ More rigourously, I should maybe write $\Gamma(\mathrm{pr}^\ast (\bigwedge^\bullet T^\ast\Sigma))$ with $\mathrm{pr}:M\to\Sigma$ being the projection.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Why are you so certain there is an error in your argument?  If I take a time-varying form $f(t) dx \wedge dy$ the partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} dx \wedge dy$ is also a form, i.e. all I'm using is that forms make a vector space.

Comment: @RyanBudney I agree that $\partial_{t}\omega$ for a $t$-dependent form on $\Sigma$ is again a $t$-dependent form on $\Sigma$, as I wrote in my question. But if I take $\omega\in\Omega^{k}(M)$ (here $M=I\times\mathbb{R}$), then I would not expect $\partial_{t}\omega$ to be a differential form. But my argument, in which I decompose $\omega$ in terms of two $t$-dependent forms on $\Sigma$, seems to imply exactly this.

Comment: As an example, take $A\in\Omega^{1}(M)$. I decompose it as $A=A_{0}d t+A_{1}$ with $A_{0}:=A(\partial_{t})$. Then, $A_{0}\in C^{\infty}(M)$ and $A_{1}\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},\Omega^{1}(\Sigma))$. Clearly, also $\partial_{t}A_{0}\in C^{\infty}(M)$ and $\partial_{t}A_{1}\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},\Omega^{1}(\Sigma))$, as you said. Then, $\partial_{t}A=(\partial_{t}A_{0})d t+\partial_{t}A_{1}$. Now, the isomorphism of sections I wrote in my question implies that $\partial_{t}A\in\Omega^{1}(M)$, which is what confuses me, since in general partial derivatives of tensors are not again tensors...

Comment: *in my first comment it should be $M=I\times\Sigma$ of course

Comment: [My apologies for mixing up $M$ and $\Sigma$ above] Here's the simple explanation. Differentiation with respect to time on $(p,q)$-tensors is simply Lie differentiation by the vector field $\partial_t$ (whose flow on $M = I \times \Sigma$ is simply translation on the factor $I$),

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić I see, so $\partial_{t}$ maps tensor fields to tensor fields on manifolds of the type above. That clears my confusion. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, using Cartan's formula for the Lie derivative, it is quite easy to see that $\mathcal{L}_{\partial_{t}}=\partial_{t}$ on $\Omega^{\bullet}(M)$. I should have noticed earlier.

Comment: Is your question answered?  Generally speaking when you have an object moving in a vector space, all the regular constructions from calculus work.  The complexities with forms arise when you ask for more complicated comparisons, i.e. when you are comparing two objects defined on distinct tangent spaces, etc.

Comment: @RyanBudney yes it is answered, thank you!